# Input tensor for a sequential model in keras

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

When building a Keras model with the functional API in R, it is possible to not convert your data frames to a data matrix and therefore keep the column names.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(tfdatasets)
tensorflow::set_random_seed(42)

boston_housing <- dataset_boston_housing()

c(train_data, train_labels) %<-% boston_housing$train
c(test_data, test_labels) %<-% boston_housing$test

paste0("Training entries: ", length(train_data), ", labels: ", length(train_labels))

library(dplyr)

column_names <- c('CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 
                  'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT')

train_df <- train_data %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>% 
  setNames(column_names) %>% 
  mutate(label = train_labels)

test_df <- test_data %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>% 
  setNames(column_names) %>% 
  mutate(label = test_labels)

spec <- feature_spec(train_df, label ~ . ) %>%
  step_numeric_column(all_numeric(), normalizer_fn = scaler_standard()) %>%
  fit()

spec

layer <- layer_dense_features(
  feature_columns = dense_features(spec),
  dtype = tf$float32
)
layer(train_df)

build_model <- function() {
  input <- layer_input_from_dataset(train_df %>% select(-label))
  
  output <- input %>% 
    layer_dense_features(dense_features(spec)) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1) 
  
  model <- keras_model(input, output)
  
  model %>% 
    compile(
      loss = "mse",
      optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
      metrics = list("mean_absolute_error")
    )
  
  model
}

# Display training progress by printing a single dot for each completed epoch.
print_dot_callback <- callback_lambda(
  on_epoch_end = function(epoch, logs) {
    if (epoch %% 80 == 0) cat("\n")
    cat(".")
  }
)    

model <- build_model()

history <- model %>% fit(
  x = train_df %>% select(-label),
  y = train_df$label,
  epochs = 500,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  verbose = 0,
  view_metrics = TRUE,
  callbacks = list(print_dot_callback, callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", patience = 5, restore_best_weights = TRUE))
)
```

However, I am now trying to build the same model as a sequential model and do all that without converting train_df and test_df to a matrix where I need to delete the column names. When I exchange the functional way of building a keras model above with the below sequential way

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_dense(
    units = 64,
    activation = "relu",
    input_shape = c(13)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64,
              activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)
```

I am getting a value error:

```
ValueError: Missing data for input "dense_93_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']. Expected the following keys: ['dense_93_input']

See `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details
```

What do I need to adjust so that the sequential model recognices and expects the column names of train_df as input to the first layer, instead of expecting a `dense_input` object?